# Redirection after certain notification display

Tags: php

I am struggling with this code

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($check_mem_id)!= mysqli_num_rows($check_mem_name)) {
echo "<script> alert('ID ALREADY REGISTERED') </script>";
header("Location: http://localhost/check/admin/add.php");


 }
```

The thing is, this code overrides the notification and goes directly to the page with blank fields. I want the notification/alert to appear, and after I hit OK it should go back to the page I was filling and all information are still there in the fields.

Comment: you do it the other way round, first redirect then show the message

Comment: or, rather include that add.php instead of redirecting, and fill the data